# Xparh парсер. Как получить доступ к атрибутам ссылки С#

Tags: c#, парсер, xmlparser

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> name = new List<string>();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(@"http://slova.by/JSON_test/ParsingPage.html");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[@class='mylinks']");

        foreach (XmlNode i in nodeList)
        {
            name.Add(i["a"].InnerText);

        }

        listBox1.DataSource = name;
    }
```

Разбираюсь с парсером сайтов. Но ни как не могу понять как сформировать запрос к атрибутам ссылок title

Comment: А где вы тут увидели XML?

Comment: это html. Там по коду разница не принципиальная.
А что посоветуете для парсинга html. Может есть ссылка где разжевано как парсить? :)

Comment: HTML != XML, да, его можно распарсить как XML, но не все и не всегда. Советую использовать подходящие для этого инструменты!

Comment: как всегда спасибо вам Евгений. В который раз помогаете:)

Comment: Рекомендую NuGet пакет `HtmlAgilityPack`. Ссылка на подробности о нем дана модератором в самом верху.